# Proof Verification Language

Tags: solution-verification

Sometimes I write proofs, but I have no one to ask if it indeed makes sense.

I was wondering if there is some type of language where tell it the tools I have to prove this statement, the statement and my proof, and it can tell me if the proof is correct.

Comment: You mean, as in an automated verification of a formal proof that a computer can perform?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I've been looking around I was able to find something called [coq](https://coq.inria.fr/)